# Avoid adding view on every click in MultiTouchListener using java

Tags: java, android

When I Click on a view then border around that view and view2 is adding on every click which create jerk like effect or blinking .

I simply avoid blinking effect for this code any reference for this

this is the code that I'm using right now.

```
multiTouchListener = getMultiTouchListener();
                            multiTouchListener.setOnGestureControl(new MultiTouchListener.OnGestureControl() {
                                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                                @Override
                                public void onClick() {
                                    if (filter_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                                        filter_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    if (sticker_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                                        sticker_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                text_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                Rect myRect = new Rect();
                                view1.getGlobalVisibleRect(myRect);
                                int newX = myRect.left;
                                int newY = myRect.top;

                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            frmBorder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border_tv);
                                            final View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(EditingActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.pop_up_text, frameLayout, false);
                                            final TextView imgPhotoEditorEdit = view2.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorEdit);
                                            final TextView imgPhotoEditorClose = view2.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorClose);
                                            view2.setElevation(20);
                                            frameLayout.addView(view2);   

                                            Rect rectf = new Rect();
                                            //For coordinates location relative to the parent
                                            selected_View.getLocalVisibleRect(rectf);
                                            //For coordinates location relative to the screen/display
                                            selected_View.getGlobalVisibleRect(rectf);

                                            Rect myViewRect = new Rect();
                                            selected_View.getGlobalVisibleRect(myViewRect);
                                            float x = myViewRect.left;
                                            float y = myViewRect.top;

                                            Log.d("WIDTH        :", String.valueOf(rectf.width()));
                                            Log.d("HEIGHT       :", String.valueOf(rectf.height()));
                                            Log.d("left         :", String.valueOf(rectf.left) + "    " + x);
                                            Log.d("right        :", String.valueOf(rectf.right));
                                            Log.d("top          :", String.valueOf(rectf.top) + "    " + y);
                                            Log.d("bottom       :", String.valueOf(rectf.bottom));

                                            View rootLayout = selected_View.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

                                            int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
                                            selected_View.getLocationInWindow(viewLocation);

                                            int[] rootLocation = new int[2];
                                            rootLayout.getLocationInWindow(rootLocation);

                                            int relativeLeft = viewLocation[0] - rootLocation[0];
                                            int relativeTop = viewLocation[1] - rootLocation[1];

                                            float cx = rectf.exactCenterX();
                                            float cy = rectf.exactCenterY();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect you're experiencing is likely due to the fact that you're adding view2 to the frameLayout on every click in your onClick method. To avoid this and add the view only once, you can introduce a boolean flag to check if the view has already been added. Here's how you can modify your code.

```
// Declare a boolean flag to track if view2 is already added
boolean view2Added = false;

multiTouchListener = getMultiTouchListener();
multiTouchListener.setOnGestureControl(new MultiTouchListener.OnGestureControl() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        if (filter_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            filter_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (sticker_layout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            sticker_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        text_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Rect myRect = new Rect();
        view1.getGlobalVisibleRect(myRect);
        int newX = myRect.left;
        int newY = myRect.top;

        if (!view2Added) {
            frmBorder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_border_tv);
            final View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(EditingActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.pop_up_text, frameLayout, false);
            final TextView imgPhotoEditorEdit = view2.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorEdit);
            final TextView imgPhotoEditorClose = view2.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorClose);
            view2.setElevation(20);
            frameLayout.addView(view2);
            view2Added = true; // Set the flag to true so that view2 is not added again
        }

        Rect rectf = new Rect();
        //For coordinates location relative to the parent
        selected_View.getLocalVisibleRect(rectf);
        //For coordinates location relative to the screen/display
        selected_View.getGlobalVisibleRect(rectf);

        Rect myViewRect = new Rect();
        selected_View.getGlobalVisibleRect(myViewRect);
        float x = myViewRect.left;
        float y = myViewRect.top;

        // ... Rest of your code

        Log.d("WIDTH        :", String.valueOf(rectf.width()));
        Log.d("HEIGHT       :", String.valueOf(rectf.height()));
        Log.d("left         :", String.valueOf(rectf.left) + "    " + x);
        Log.d("right        :", String.valueOf(rectf.right));
        Log.d("top          :", String.valueOf(rectf.top) + "    " + y);
        Log.d("bottom       :", String.valueOf(rectf.bottom));

        View rootLayout = selected_View.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);

        int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
        selected_View.getLocationInWindow(viewLocation);

        int[] rootLocation = new int[2];
        rootLayout.getLocationInWindow(rootLocation);

        int relativeLeft = viewLocation[0] - rootLocation[0];
        int relativeTop = viewLocation[1] - rootLocation[1];

        float cx = rectf.exactCenterX();
        float cy = rectf.exactCenterY();
    }
});
```

With this modification, the view view2 will only be added once, and subsequent clicks will not add additional views, eliminating the blinking effect.